# What is correct usage of DataSource with torch/dp library

Tags: lua, machine-learning, torch

I am new to both programming language lua and torch library. I am trying to get some machine learning algorithms to work ASAP. I tried to get neural nets using dp library using example [here](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp/blob/master/examples/neuralnetwork.lua). But I am unable to get my dataset into the form to feed into learning algorithm. I think my best and also initial guess was to do this:

```
train_set = dp.DataSet(dataset[1], dataset[2]) 
test_set = dp.DataSet(test_dataset[1], test_dataset[2])

ds = dp.DataSource(train_set=train_set, test_set=test_set)
```

Which gives error:  `filename.lua:56: ')' expected near '='`

Where dataset[ 1] is a torch.Tensor containing information about the data and dataset[2] is torch.Tensor of binary information about the data I would like know.

Hope it is not a stupid syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is a syntax error. Lua has no named arguments. Lua adepts [use table to emulate such a feature](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.3.html).

So, try this:
`dp.DataSource({train_set=train_set, test_set=test_set})`

or just
`dp.DataSource{train_set=train_set, test_set=test_set}`
 (you can remove parenthesis if a function has one parameter).